# PayUmoney Integration with angularjs giving Checksum failed error

Tags: angularjs, payment-gateway, payumoney

I am trying to integrate payumoney with angularjs. But it shows error like 'checksum failed'.

### controller.js

```
(function ()
{
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app.todo')
    .controller('TodoController', TodoController);

/** @ngInject */
function TodoController($document, $mdDialog, $mdSidenav, Tasks, Tags,$scope,$crypthmac)
{
    var vm = this;

    vm.txnid = "fd3e847h2";
    vm.firstname = "Hemanth";
    vm.email = "kevinguru888@gmail.com";
    vm.phone = "9901996148";
    vm.service_provider = "payu_paisa";
    vm.productinfo = "steering";
    vm.amount = "399.00";
    vm.surl = "http://localhost:3000/success";
    vm.furl = "http://localhost:3000/failure";
    vm.key = "OygoFs";
    vm.salt = "BV1QBwCv";

    var string = vm.key + '|' + vm.txnid + '|' + vm.amount + '|' + vm.productinfo + '|' + vm.firstname + '|' + vm.email + '|||||||||||' + vm.salt;
    vm.hash = $crypthmac.encrypt(string,"");


}
})();
```

### html file

```
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src="../bower_components/angular-hmac-   sha512/angular-hmac-sha512.js"></script>
</head>

<div id="todo" class="page-layout simple tabbed">

<!-- HEADER -->
<div class="header md-accent-bg" layout="row" layout-align="start center">
     <div class="title">
        <span class="md-display-1 font-weight-300">PAY U Form</span>
     </div>

</div>
<!-- / HEADER -->
<md-content layout-padding>
    <div class="innerContent">
        <form action='https://test.payu.in/_payment', method='post', name="buyDetailsForm">
            <md-content class="md-padding">
                <div layout="row" layout-align="space-around">
                    <div flex style="max-width:400px;">
                        <md-input-container class="md-block">
                            <label>Transaction Id</label>
                            <input name="txnid" ng-model="vm.txnid">
                        </md-input-container>
                    </div>

                    <div flex style="max-width:400px;">
                        <md-input-container class="md-block">
                            <label>Name</label>
                            <input name='firstname' ng-model="vm.firstname">
                        </md-input-container>
                    </div>

                    <div flex style="max-width:400px;">
                        <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
                            <label>Email</label>
                            <input name='email' ng-model="vm.email">
                        </md-input-container>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div layout="row" layout-align="space-around">
                    <div flex style="max-width:400px;">
                        <md-input-container class="md-block">
                            <label>Mobile</label>
                            <input name='phone' ng-model="vm.phone">
                        </md-input-container>
                    </div>

                    <div flex style="max-width:400px;">
                        <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
                            <label>Service Provider</label>
                            <input name='service_provider' ng-model="vm.service_provider">
                        </md-input-container>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div layout="row" layout-align="space-around">
                    <div flex style="max-width:400px;">
                        <md-input-container class="md-block">
                            <label>Product Info</label>
                            <input name='productinfo' ng-model="vm.productinfo">
                        </md-input-container>
                    </div>

                    <div flex style="max-width:400px;">
                        <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
                            <label>Amount</label>
                            <input name='amount' ng-model="vm.amount">
                        </md-input-container>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div layout="row" layout-align="space-around">
                    <div flex style="max-width:400px;">
                        <md-input-container class="md-block">
                            <label>Success Url</label>
                            <input name='surl' ng-model="vm.surl">
                        </md-input-container>
                    </div>

                    <div flex style="max-width:400px;">
                        <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
                            <label>Failure Url</label>
                            <input name='furl' ng-model="vm.furl">
                        </md-input-container>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div layout="row" layout-align="space-around">
                    <div flex style="max-width:400px;">
                        <md-input-container class="md-block">
                            <label>Key</label>
                            <input name='key' ng-model="vm.key">
                        </md-input-container>
                    </div>

                    <div flex style="max-width:400px;">
                        <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
                            <label>Hash</label>
                            <input name='hash' ng-model="vm.hash">
                        </md-input-container>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </md-content>
            <div layout="row" layout-align="end center">
                <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="vm.cancel()">Cancel</md-button>
                <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="vm.submit(buyDetailsForm)">Place Order</md-button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</md-content>   
</div>
```

The error shows like "SORRY! We were unable to process your payment Checksum Failed".

Answer (score 0):

This error occurrs when hash and passing value in form doesn't match.
If you are passing 2 udf then you must also send it in form with name.

And if you are passing the same but still got the same error, then it is because of the problem in generation in hash. You are using `$crypthmac` but it doesn't create perfect hash, to create either use or own `sha512` algorithm, or use an `API`, to create the perfect hash. You can check that hash created by `$crypthmac` is not that perfect that `PayUMoney` decrypt it perfectly, that's why it returns error. Just check has generated with `$crypthmac` and `<?php echo hash('sha512', 'text') ?>` you can get the difference.